# Adding to user metadata after an object has been created in Google Cloud Store

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine

### I want to add user metadata that is calculated from the stream as it is uploaded

I am using the [Google Cloud Storage Client](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) from inside a `Servlet` during a file upload.

The only solutions I can come up and tried are not really satisfactory for a couple of reasons.

1. Buffer the stream in memory, calculate the metadata as the stream is buffered then write the stream out to the Cloud Store after it has been completely read.
2. Write the stream to a bucket and calculate the metadata. Then read the object from the temporary bucket and write it to its final location with the calculated metadata.
3. Pre-calculate the metadata on the client and send it with the upload.

#### Why these aren't acceptable:

1. Doesn't work for large objects, which some of these will be.
2. Will cost a fortune if lots of objects are uploaded, which there will be.
3. Can't trust the clients, and some of the clients can't calculate some of what I need.

#### Is there any way to update the metadata of a Google Cloud Store object after the fact?

Comment: Is patch an option: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/patch#examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are likely using the [Google Cloud Storage Java Client for AppEngine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) library. This library is great for AppEngine users, but it offers only a subset of the features of Google Cloud Storage. It does not to my knowledge happen to support updating the metadata of existing objects. However, Google Cloud Storage definitely supports this.

You can use the [Google API Java client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/), which exposes the Google Cloud Storage's JSON API. With this library, you'll be able to use the [storage.objects.update](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/update) method or the [storage.objects.patch](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/patch) method, both of which can update metadata (the difference is that update replaces any properties of the object that are already there, while patch just changes the specified fields). The code would look something like this:

```
StorageObject objectMetadata = new StorageObject();
    .setName("OBJECT_NAME")
    .setMetadata(ImmutableMap.of("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"));
Storage.Objects.Patch patchObject = storage.objects().patch("mybucket", objectMetadata);
patchObject.execute();
```